# I want to send image using post method

Tags: android, http-post, multipartform-data

I want to send a picture file on a web server, but I get an error while running this code.

```
hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

URI u = null;
try {
    u = new URI(params[0]);
    HttpPost hp = new HttpPost();
    hp.setURI(u);


    System.out.println("start");
    MultipartEntity mp=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    System.out.println("mul");
    FileBody fb=new FileBody(new File("akash/res/drawable-hdpi/hp.jpg"),"image/jpg");
    fb.getMediaType();
    mp.addPart("picture",fb);

    System.out.println("add picture");
    hp.setEntity(mp);
    System.out.println("set entity");

    HttpResponse hr = null;
    hr = hc.execute(hp);
    System.out.println(hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the the permission for internet use in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```